# Compare a dict to itself and remove similar keys efficiently

Tags: python

I would like to compare elements in a dictionary to one another, and remove items according to some comparison criteria. And I'd love it to be efficient. I have a function that can do this, but it repeatedly copies the dictionay. Surely there is a superior way:

```
mydict = {1:5,2:7,3:9,4:9,7:7,8:0,111:43,110:77}

def partial_duplicate_destroyer(mydict,tolerance):
    for key1 in mydict.keys():
        mydict_copy = mydict.copy()
        for key2 in mydict_copy.keys():
            if key2 - tolerance < key1 < key2 + tolerance and not(key1 == key2):
                del(mydict[key1])
                break
    return mydict

print partial_duplicate_destroyer(mydict,2)
print partial_duplicate_destroyer(mydict,20)
print partial_duplicate_destroyer(mydict,200)

#correct output:
# {4: 9, 8: 0, 111: 43}
# {8: 0, 111: 43}
# {111: 43}
```

Comment: If there are a pair of keys within the tolerance of each other, does it matter which is deleted?

Comment: @David Robinson - No it doesn't, but in the example above when the tolerance=2, only one key out of 1,2,3,4 should remain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This approach could be reduced down to:

```
from itertools import combinations

def partial_duplicate_destroyer(mydict, tolerance):
    #Modifies in-place. Returns only as a convenience. Copy if you don't want this behaviour.
    for key1, key2 in combinations(mydict, 2):
       if key1 in mydict and key2 - tolerance < key1 < key2 + tolerance:
         del mydict[key1]
    return mydict
```

If we try this:

```
>>> mydict = {1:5,2:7,3:9,4:9,7:7,8:0,111:43,110:77}
>>> partial_duplicate_destroyer(mydict, 2)
{4: 9, 8: 0, 111: 43}
>>> partial_duplicate_destroyer(mydict, 20)
{8: 0, 111: 43}
>>> partial_duplicate_destroyer(mydict, 200)
{111: 43}
>>> mydict
{111: 43}
```

This uses [`itertools.combinations()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to produce all possible combinations of keys (without repeating). This is much more efficient as you don't bother working where you have the keys the same, and it's done more efficiently in C rather than your side with Python.

Note that here you are modifying `mydict` in place - that is at the end of this, `mydict` is `{111: 43}` - you need to copy the dict and work on it in the function, rather than directly on it, if you don't want this behaviour. This is what is shown in the last line.

Comment: Thats looking great, and your first version with `product` seemed fine too.

Comment: @fraxel Product worked, but it meant you had to manually filter out repeated results and results where the keys were the same. Using combinations will be faster and not give results you don't need, reducing the checks you need to do - win-win.

Comment: This will throw a `KeyError` even for simple examples like `mydict = {1.5:None, 1:None, 2:None}` and tolerance `0.75`. (The example is implementation-dependent, but this works for pypy and CPython).

Comment: jorgeca: Ah, was overzealous when removing checks from my permutations version, I have fixed this. Good spot.

Comment: By the way, the example shows that this problem doesn't have a well defined solution. Should the answer be `{1:None}` or `{1.5:None, 2:None}`? ;)

Comment: The OP did comment and say that didn't matter, so long as they were spaced by at least the tolerance.

Comment: @jorgeca - Thankyou! Interesting catch. Resolved by changing to: `combinations(sorted(mydict), 2)`. As in your example: `{1.5:None, 1:None, 2:None}`, with tolerance `0.75`, I want any element returned, BUT only one element. My original question may have been slightly under scoped.